# How can we find the maximum value of $S=|a_1-b_1|+|a_2-b_2|+...+|a_n-b_n|\ ?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $M$ be a positive integer such that $M>2$.  Choose $2n$ positive integers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, ... b_n$ not greater than $M$ such that $a_1< a_2< ...< a_n \leq M$, $b_1< b_2< ... <b_n \leq M$ and $$a_1+a_2+...+a_n=b_1+b_2+...+b_n$$

What is the maximum value of $$S=|a_1-b_1|+|a_2-b_2|+...+|a_n-b_n|$$ that $S$ could get ?

If the condition

> $a_1< a_2< ...< a_n \leq M$, $b_1< b_2< ... <b_n \leq M$

is replaced by the condition

> $a_i \neq a_j$ with $i\neq j$ and $b_k \neq b_l$ with $k \neq l$ ($a_i$'s doesn't have to be different from $b_j$'s with any $i, j$)

would the maximum value of $S$ remain the same ?

I tried to use the inequality $|a|+|b| \geq |a+b|$ but it didn't work. Is it possible to find the maximum value of $S$ ?

(Edit: Thank you Sasha Kozachinskiy for your answer in the case $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$ weren't distinct integers, I have edited the question)

(sorry, English is my second language)

Comment: What has this to do woth `linear-algebra`? Or with `abstract-algebra`?

Comment: Hint: Use that $$|x|\geq 0$$ for all real $x$

Comment: There is very little to maximize after you let $a_i,b_i$ be given.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the following upper bound holds: $S \le n (M - 1)$.

This upper bound is tight when $n$ is even. Indeed, you can take:
\begin{align*}
&a_1 = \ldots = a_{n/2} = M, \qquad &&a_{n/2 + 1} = \ldots = a_n = 1,\\
&b_1 = \ldots = b_{n/2} = 1, \qquad &&b_{n/2 + 1} = \ldots = b_n = M.
\end{align*}

When $n$ is odd the maximal possible value of $S$ is $(n - 1) (M - 1)$. It is easy to come up with an example achieving this bound (modify the previous example). Now we have to show that $S_n \le (n - 1)(M - 1)$. Assume that $n = 2k + 1$. Define 
$$U = \{i\in\{1, 2, \ldots, n\} : a_i \ge b_i\}, \qquad V = \{i\in\{1, 2, \ldots, n\} : a_i < b_i\}.$$
Note that
$$S = \sum\limits_{i\in U} a_i + \sum\limits_{i\in V} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in U} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in V} a_i.$$ 
Using the fact that 
$$a_1 + \ldots + a_n = b_1 + \ldots + b_n,$$
we can rewrite $S$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
S &=  \sum\limits_{i\in U} a_i + \sum\limits_{i\in V} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in U} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in V} a_i = \sum\limits_{i\in U} a_i + (\sum\limits_{i\in U} a_i + \sum\limits_{i\in V} a_i - \sum\limits_{i\in U} b_i) - \sum\limits_{i\in U} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in V} a_i \\
&= 2 \sum\limits_{i\in U} (a_i - b_i) \le 2 |U| \cdot (M - 1).
\end{align*}
Also you can write
\begin{align*}
S &=  \sum\limits_{i\in U} a_i + \sum\limits_{i\in V} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in U} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in V} a_i = (\sum\limits_{i\in U} b_i + \sum\limits_{i\in V} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in V} a_i) + \sum\limits_{i\in V} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in U} b_i - \sum\limits_{i\in V} a_i \\
&\le 2 \sum\limits_{i\in V} (b_i - a_i) \le 2 |V| \cdot (M - 1).
\end{align*}
By noticing that either $|U|$ or $|V|$ is at most $k$, we obtain $|S| \le 2k(M - 1) = (n - 1)(M - 1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that $a_i$, $b_i$ are integers. Now it's fixed, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I have edited the question, $a_i$'s must be distinct positive integers, $b_i$'s must be distinct ($a_i$ can be equal to $b_j$) Can you find the maximum value of $S$ in this case ?